# Is it possible to process JSON and accessing parameters using service bus?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have seen that it is possible to add a [JSON schema](https://www.robfox.nl/2016/04/19/adding-json-schema-logic-app/) when you are using the "HTTP Request"-trigger and adding the JSON schema in the "Request Body JSON Schema"-box.

I have also looked at adding schema in the "Integration Account", however the section in the documentation says its "to confirm that XML documents you receive are valid", which is not what i am looking for.

I am using a Azure Service Bus Queue.
In this case i am having PeekLock as a trigger, the idea is that the input in the service bus will be of a certain format. It will all be in JSON. I dont "care" or need to know what happens before the service bus, all i know is that each message will contain the same format. What my logic app is supposed to do is to receive the message in the service bus and then mail it to whoever its supposed to go to, and add if there is anything to add from blob storage. I want to be able to access certain "tags" or "parameters", since Service Bus only have its own few tags.

I used the [jsonschema.net](http://jsonschema.net) to get the schema, and here is the JSON of how a format will look like:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "Key": "XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX",
      "type": "Email",
      "data": {
        "subject": "Who is the father?",
        "bodyBlobUID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "to": [
          "darth.vader@hotmail.com"
        ],
        "cc": [
          "luke.skywalker@nomail.com"
        ],
        "bcc": [
          "leia.skywalker@nomail.com"
        ],
        "encoding": "System.Text.UTF8Encoding",
        "isBodyHtml": false,
        "organisationUID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "BlobUIDs": [
          "luke.skywalker@nomail.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So my questions are of 2 parts:

- 1: Is it possible to add JSON schemas without using the HTTP Request
  trigger for using service bus?
- 2: If #1 is possible, or maybe it can
  be done in another way. How do i access the tags or parameters of the
  JSON format? At this moment i am trying to do transformations using
  schemas and maps with the Integration account but it seems
  unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: **Parse JSON** is now available in Logic Apps.

we will be releasing an action called **JSON Parse** next week, in which you can specify the service bus output as payload, define schema of the payload, then custom friendly tokens in subsequent steps.

Comment: Hi Derek Li.
With the new JSON Parse action, most of my problems are solved. However i do have one more issue i can´t figure out. Since my "to", "cc" etc is an array.
The problem is when im trying to access the array. (Maybe there is a better way, if it is i would like to know).
I use @{item()['data']['to']} when i only have 1 email-adress in "to", the raw translation is "["darth.vader@hotmail.com"]". Don´t know why it adds the "[]" brackets. Which when i try to use the outlook send mail action fails due to invalid recipient. Im using service bus trigger -> json parse -> send mail action.

Comment: If the particular property is an array, it will still be an array even when there's one item in it. In this case, I think it's the best to put the array object in an "For-each" loop, and use the send email action within for each loop to send email to each recipients.

Comment: Yes i tried that. However the problem is since its an "item". So if i try to use the for-each loop for "to" i get the following error: "The output you selected is inside a collection and needs to be looped over to be accessed. This action cannot be inside a foreach." http://imgur.com/gkGaGwV : And i cant find anything on this either. Which (i guess) means i have to use the for-each loop for "items" but then the original problem exist. Since i cant use a for-each loop inside the for-each, or any other loop for "to".

Comment: I see, looks like the array of recipients is inside another array ("items"), so in this case, you will need nested for-each loops, which isn't supported today. As a workaround, you can create a child Logic App, that accepts an array of recipients as input and use for-each to traverse thru all items, and in your current workflow, call the child Logic App, this way. Let me know if that make sense, feel free to reach out to me at Derek.Li (at) Microsoft dot com as well.